# Opacity transition event not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make a menu appear when a certain button is clicked, I tried it with a "slide in from the side(?)" transition, which worked. The width property goes from 0% to 100%. I wanted to change this to opacity going from 0 to 1 instead, which broke the thing.

If I manually change the opacity either to 0 or 1 I get the desired result, it seems like the onClick event doesn't fire anymore.

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
 <!-- Main Navigation Menu -->
 <div id="fullScreenMenu" class="overlay">
     <!-- Menu Content -->
     <div class="overlay-content">
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And

```
<span onclick="openNav()" class="float-left button">                           
    MENU
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {    
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0; /* Starting Opacity */
position: fixed;
z-index: 1; 
left: 0;
top: 0;    
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9); 
overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

**JS**

```
function openNav() {
     document.getElementById("fullScreenMenu").style.opacity = "1.0";
}

function closeNav() {
     document.getElementById("fullScreenMenu").style.opacity = "0.0";
}
```

Comment: Your Menu is covering the entire screen, the click registers on the menu, not the `<span>`.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, I feel stupid now

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/w34mkevw/

Comment: Thanks man, that worked perfectly. Post this as an answer so I can give you some rep.

Comment: I would, but the timeout thing is a dirty workaround. With jQuery, you'd simply do `$("#fullScreenMenu").fadeIn();` so I'm hesitant to post this as answer, doubly so because your question was mostly about the click not registering.

Comment: Are you saying that I made it unnecessarily complicated for myself again

Comment: Not sure about that, but your question was mostly about the click, not the fading.